# What is the HTTP header :host, :method, :path, :scheme, :version used for?

Tags: security, http, http-headers

I have seen that Twitter and Facebook is using :host, :method, :path, :scheme, :version in their HTTP requests. I just wonder what they are used for?

[image]

My first guess is that they use custom headers to prevent CSRF attacks. But you only need one header to prevent CSRF attacks not 5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might be SPDY or experimental HTTP/2.0. See http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-http2-09.html#HttpRequest

Comment: is there any way to retrieve these?

Comment: Pseudo header fields (now in HTTP/2 and HTTP/3) are not real header fields. They aren't accesible through header field APIs, consistent with how this information is handled in HTTP/1.1.